# In mongodb c# how can I limit a facet search to a specific set of ids?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

Here is what I would like to accomplish:

```
var idFilter = Builders<TProduct>.Filter.In(x => x.Id, aListOfStringIds);

var aggResultArray = await Repository.Aggregate()
    .SearchMeta(Builders<TProduct>.Search
        .Facet(Builders<TProduct>.Search
            .Compound()
            .Filter(idFilter)
            .Must(must)
            .Should(should), facets), indexName: SearchIndex)
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

My problem is that a facet search does not support .In

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Tried querystring but could not get that to work with ObjectIds and so nothing matched.